# Vue does not do vendor auto-prefixing of the css property. Why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, documentation, prefix

Vue does not do vendor auto-prefixing of the css property. Why?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" :style="styleObj">foo</div>

    <script>
      var a = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: { styleObj: { transition: "all 1s linear" } }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is what I see in Chrome (Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (arm64)):

[image]

I am expecting to see something like:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear;
-ms-transition: all 1s linear;
-o-transition: all 1s linear;
transition: all 1s linear;
```

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Auto-prefixing) is the official documentation which states that the auto-prefixing should happen. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think this feature is done via `vue-loader` only, and will only work for `<style>` part in SFC files, or `:style`in `<template>` tag. In any case it won't work for dynamic style put in `data` AFAIK.

Comment: @Kapcash, documentation says nothing about what you just said. :(